# Constructing an index based on index values of multiple DataFrames to be joined

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, left-join

I need to combine multiple DataFrames into a single one. All of them have integer index that I would like to preserve in the result.

Example:

df_1

```
     a
  0  1
  1  3
  5  10
  7  2
```

df_2

```
     b
  2  4
  4  11
  7  3
  9  4
```

Result:

```
     a    b
  0  1    -
  1  3    -
  2  -    4
  4  -    11
  5  10   -
  7  2    3
  9  -    4
```

So far I have been using such an approach and I would like to know if there is a cleaner solution:

```
dfs = [df_1, df_2, ...]
join_index = list()
for df in dfs:
    join_index.extend(df.index.tolist())
join_index = sorted(list(set(join_index)))
```

The join_index is then used when joining the DataFrames together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html), indices are union  of all indices of `DataFrame`s in `list` and also are sorted:

```
dfs = [df_1, df_2]
df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)
print (df)
      a     b
0   1.0   NaN
1   3.0   NaN
2   NaN   4.0
4   NaN  11.0
5  10.0   NaN
7   2.0   3.0
9   NaN   4.0
```